# Spring Data Rest - Proxy path not including link path

Tags: spring-data-rest

I'm proxying a Spring REST backend like so:

Backend:
`http://backend:8080`

Proxied localhost:

`localhost:3000/api/backend -> http://backend:8080`

If I browse locally to a proxied endpoint, it will proxy the request, the links, however, do not include the proxy path, i.e.

`GET localhost:3000/api/backend/people`

`"href": "http://localhost:3000/people"`

I would expect this to be:

`"href": "http://localhost:3000/api/backend/people"`

There any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at the `x-forwarded-*`headers your proxy is adding to the request.

If the request from your proxy to the backend contains the header `x-forwarded-prefix=/api/backend` spring will pick up the prefix and add it to the generated link.

You do not mention which proxy are you using so I cannot tell if your proxy supports adding the `x-forwarded-prefix` header.

Comment: I ran into this problem a while back, but I had an even more complicated situation `http://local/api/people` -> `http://backend/context/people`.  I didn't have a solution except changing the backend context to be `api`  Does adding the x-forwarded-prefix overwrite the context or does it prepend to the context?

Comment: It worked!  I was just browsing the spring code trying to find an answer.  This was just a webpack proxy for a local deploy.  So the following worked (webpack.config.js):  devServer: {
    contentBase: 'build/',
    proxy: {
      '/api/person*': {
        target: 'http://backend:8080',
        rewrite: function(req) {
          req.headers['X-Forwarded-Prefix'] = '/api/person'
          req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/api\/person/, '');
        }
      }
    },
    port: 3000
  }