# nginx reverse proxy + Spring ResourceSupport produces wrong URL path prefix

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nginx, spring-hateoas, maven-tomcat-plugin

Spring HATEOAS ResourceSupport is generating incorrect URLs in its responses. I am using Tomcat with Spring and NGINX as a reverse proxy.

Spring generated URL: `http://localhost:8080/spring-ng-seed`

Project URL: `https://spring-ng-seed.dev/` (serves static content),

Web API URL: `https://spring-ng-seed.dev/wapi/`

All requests to `/wapi/` work fine however Spring HATEOAS's ResourceSupport is generating urls that look like:
`https://spring-ng-seed.dev/spring-ng-seed/foo/bar`
instead of
`https://spring-ng-seed.dev/wapi/foo/bar`

For example, a self rel when we call `https://spring-ng-seed.dev/wapi/foo/bar` we end up with `https://spring-ng-seed.dev/spring-ng-seed/foo/bar` coming back as self rel which is incorrect.

`/spring-ng-seed/foo/bar` should be `/wapi/foo/bar` in the response links.

I am not sure what is configured wrong, nginx, tomcat or spring but I cannot find anything on this anywhere else.

I am also using AngularJS on the front end but I doubt that the problem lays with the front end but rather with nginx as a reverse proxy or tomcat.

Can anyone help please?

NGINX Config:

```
server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.spring-ng-seed.dev spring-ng-seed.dev;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate           /Users/reecefowell/Projects/Spring/spring-ng-seed/cert.pem;        # path to your cacert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key       /Users/reecefowell/Projects/Spring/spring-ng-seed/server.key;    # path to your privkey.pem
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers               ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /wapi/ {   
        proxy_pass               http://localhost:8080/spring-ng-seed/;
        proxy_read_timeout       90;
        proxy_connect_timeout    90;
        # proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix $http_x_forwarded_prefix;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_x_forwarded_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme https;
    }

    location / {
        root /Users/reecefowell/Projects/Spring/spring-ng-seed/src/main/webapp/app/build;

        index index.html;
    }
}
```

My Tomcat is configured via my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>spring-ng-seed</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ng-seed</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <!--<configuration>-->
                    <!--<url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>-->
                    <!--<server>localhost</server>-->
                <!--</configuration>-->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please have a look at the Proxy headers that your request contains when it hits your service. spring-hateoas would process the `x-forwarded-prefix` header and prepend it to your path.

Have a look at this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36163242/5371736

Comment: I did as you asked, and I changed the following configuration:
`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /wapi;`

No effect.

I checked the output of the headers received in Springs `HttpServletRequest` and this is what I found:

`Host: "spring-ng-seed.dev"`
`X-Real-IP: "127.0.0.1"`
`X-Forwarded-Proto: "https"`
`X-Forwarded-Prefix: "/wapi"`
`X-Forwarded-Host: null`
`X-Forwarded-For: "127.0.0.1"`
`X-NginX-Proxy: true`

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Support for `X-Forwarded-Prefix` was only [added in Spring 4.1.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/7f11c1ee2f802b3a2a5b821c821b15c6705dc085), based on your POM it seems you are using Spring 4.0.5?